# Not able to create parquet files in hdfs using spark shell

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, parquet

I want to create parquet file in hdfs and then read it through hive as external table. I'm struck with stage failures in spark-shell while writing parquet files.

**Spark Version: 1.5.2
Scala Version: 2.10.4
Java: 1.7**

**Input file:(employee.txt)**

1201,satish,25
1202,krishna,28
1203,amith,39
1204,javed,23
1205,prudvi,23

**In Spark-Shell:**

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val employee = sc.textFile("employee.txt")
employee.first()
val schemaString = "id name age"
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType};
val schema = StructType(schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName ⇒ StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
val rowRDD = employee.map(_.split(",")).map(e ⇒ Row(e(0).trim.toInt, e(1), e(2).trim.toInt))
val employeeDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
val finalDF = employeeDF.toDF();
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
var WriteParquet= finalDF.write.parquet("/user/myname/schemaParquet")
```

When I type the last command I get,

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DXHz.png)

[SPARK APPLICATION MANAGER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9oDa.png)

I even tried increasing the executor memory, its still failing.
Also Importantly , finalDF.show() is producing the same error.
So, I believe I have made a logical error here.

Thanks for supporting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is you are creating a schema with all the fields/columns type defaulted to **StringType**. But while passing the values in the schema, the value of **Id** and **Age** is being converted to Integer as per the code.Hence, throwing the Matcherror while running.

The data types of columns in the schema should match the data type of values being passed to it. Try the below code.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val employee = sc.textFile("employee.txt")
employee.first()
//val schemaString = "id name age"
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._;
val schema = StructType(StructField("id", IntegerType, true) :: StructField("name", StringType, true) :: StructField("age", IntegerType, true) :: Nil)
val rowRDD = employee.map(_.split(" ")).map(e ⇒ Row(e(0).trim.toInt, e(1), e(2).trim.toInt))
val employeeDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
val finalDF = employeeDF.toDF();
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
var WriteParquet= finalDF.write.parquet("/user/myname/schemaParquet")
```

This code should run fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response Nitin,

Comment: It worked perfectly, there is a small mistake here, it should be                     //val rowRDD = employee.map(_.split(",")).map(e ⇒ Row(e(0).trim.toInt, e(1), e(2).trim.toInt)) //                                                                                                                                                                                 you missed a comma , but thank you so much for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, I was working on a text file seperated by spaces while testing. Hence, missed the comma. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Also, It reports value split is not a member of my class package AND reports application does not take any parameters when I try the whole thing in IntelliJ IDE. Do you know what dependency i need to add?

Comment: Are you using sbt or Maven? I was able to run the same code in Eclipse with Maven. Added the below dependencies to pom.xml
   `   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
      </dependency>`

Can you paste the error message and sbt/pom.xml file?

Comment: I don't have any error in  my maven pom.xml file. I have all those dependencies that you have mentioned. Its just split method cannot be resolved.